# Can a second shortcut key be added to an Anaconda keymap?

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublime-anaconda

The following entry exists in the default keymap for the Anaconda plugin for Sublime (it brings up the documentation for a method):

```
{
    command": "anaconda_doc", "keys" ["ctrl+alt+d"], "context: [
         {"key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.python"}
    ]
}
```

I'd like to add `["ctrl+."]` to the keys, so that I can press either `ctrl+alt+d` or `ctrl+.` to bring up the documentation. Is there a way to add an `or` condition to the `keys` entry?

I've tried `["ctrl+alt+d", "ctrl+."]`, but this just translates to `ctrl+alt+d+.`. None of my other attempts worked at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to add an "or" to the `keys` entry - to get another key combination to do the same thing, you have to duplicate the binding:

```
{
    "command": "anaconda_doc", "keys" ["ctrl+alt+d"], "context": [
         {"key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.python"}
    ]
},
{
    "command": "anaconda_doc", "keys" ["ctrl+."], "context": [
         {"key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.python"}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!